# Incomprehensible JMS Exception ActiveMQNotConnectedException

Tags: jms, activemq-artemis

In a project we are connecting to a server using **JMS**. We have a recurring exception approximately every month, and as we don't have access to the server side we don't know what is happening. We only have logs from our client. Below is the error trace:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ119006: Channel disconnected]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnection$JMSFailureListener.connectionFailed(ActiveMQConnection.java:728) ~[NSP.jar:NFMP_19_11]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.jms.client.ActiveMQConnection$JMSFailureListener.connectionFailed(ActiveMQConnection.java:749) ~[NSP.jar:NFMP_19_11]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.callSessionFailureListeners(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:701) ~[NSP.jar:NFMP_19_11]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.callSessionFailureListeners(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:689) ~[NSP.jar:NFMP_19_11]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.failoverOrReconnect(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:645) ~[NSP.jar:NFMP_19_11]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.handleConnectionFailure(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:504) ~[NSP.jar:NFMP_19_11]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.handleConnectionFailure(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:497) ~[NSP.jar:NFMP_19_11]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.access$100(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:72) ~[NSP.jar:NFMP_19_11]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$1.run(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:360) ~[NSP.jar:NFMP_19_11]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.OrderedExecutorFactory$OrderedExecutor$ExecutorTask.run(OrderedExecutorFactory.java:122) ~[NSP.jar:NFMP_19_11]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[?:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_45]
Caused by: org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.core.ActiveMQNotConnectedException: AMQ119006: Channel disconnected
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.connectionDestroyed(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:353) ~[NSP.jar:NFMP_19_11]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector$Listener$1.run(NettyConnector.java:956) ~[NSP.jar:NFMP_19_11]
    ... 4 more
```

As you can see:

```
javax.jms.JMSException: ActiveMQNotConnectedException[errorType=NOT_CONNECTED message=AMQ119006: Channel disconnected]
```

The error says the **Channel disconnected**. We searched for this, but we cannot understand what does it mean in the context of JMS. Is it related **to our client or to the server**?

Anyone have an idea about this specific error or JMS channels in general?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "JMS channel," per se. The *channel* referenced here is the underlying [**Netty** channel](https://netty.io/4.1/api/io/netty/channel/Channel.html) used in the JMS client implementation provided by ActiveMQ Artemis.

The stack-trace simply indicates that the channel has failed. It has been disconnected. Therefore, the client is no longer connected to the broker. There is no specific indication of *why* the channel has been disconnected. The disconnect could have been caused by the broker crashing, a network failure of some kind, etc.

Comment: Hi Justin thanks for your explication you'r right it concerns Netty, and we are analysing this issue from the service side. i'll get in touch with what w'll found